# converting Permutation to list in sage 6.2 and count some list

Tags: permutation, sage

I try to count a list in a permutation :

```
w = Permutations([])
w = w.list()
w.count([])
```

the output of last line `w.count([])` in sage 6.2 is `0` but in sage 5.0 is `1`

my question is, why this is happen????

i think the correct for that is `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be the case that way permutations are represented changed. You can see that the following commands have different outputs.

```
print type([])
print type(w[0])
```

In order to count the number of occurrences of the permutation `[]` you can begin by converting it to a Permutation. The following should do the job.

```
P = Permutations([])
elems = P.list()
elems.count(P([]))
```

Comment: Yes, some stuff regarding permutations has changed slightly.  I should also point out that the latest Sage is 6.9.